# Soft realtime on windows OS- what to consider?

Tags: windows, hardware, real-time

What consideration should we have (both software and hardware) when we build a soft-realtime application on windows : a task that occurs every XXX milliseconds and that should be completed within YYY milliseconds. (Altough consequences of missing a deadline are bad, the application can still recover from missed deadline - hence the "soft" realtime).

A few questions that already comes to my mind:
Are there registry settings that should be changed, looked at?
Is it better to use external graphic card instead of onboard video?

Example expected answer:
You should read on (and disable) [Nagle Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle_algorithm) if you use TCP as it can delay packet sending.

(This could maybe be turned in community wiki)

Comment: Is this theoretical or a problem from a class or is there an actual application behind this that you have in mind?

Comment: I would assume that a lot more details about what the application is going to be doing will be needed before really good responses can be given.

Comment: @Bart Real world applications

Comment: @Benoittr: That's a little vague. This is an actual application you're installing/implementing?

Comment: @mrdenny I was trying to keep the question as generic as possible to avoid specific local optimization. But here: one of the application receive some TCP data, does some compute intensive handling of the data, might needs to be interrupted prior to the end (and send the best solution it found to date) back via TCP. When interrupting I need to make sure to do so early enough to have time to actually send the data, but not too late or I increase the chance that I'll miss a deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware-wise, will this be running on server-class equipment? If so, the usual steps apply. Disable hyperthreading, turbo boost, and CPU C-states. Implement some level of CPU-affinity on your critical processes.

Comment: Are you aware of any guideline/patterns surrounding CPU affinity or thread priorities? Most of the time I played around with them the result always ended having a negative impact - hence I now leave affinity and thread priority alone.

Comment: I realize this answer is from 3 years ago, but I was hoping to ask: why would hyperthreading and turbo boost affect the real-time capability? If anything, it would probably improve latency, since the CPU would be able to get more done at less time, right?

Comment: @9a3eedi Because of determinism... At the time, we couldn't [control Turbo Boost](http://serverfault.com/questions/222982/monitoring-controlling-intel-turbo-boost-in-linux) and we all know Hyperthreading doesn't benefit every workload. So the sacrifice of some speed for predictable timing (especially under load) was the tradeoff.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Multimedia Class Scheduler Service](https://web.archive.org/web/20130307112620/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684247(v=vs.85).aspx)

From the doc

> The Multimedia Class Scheduler service (MMCSS) enables multimedia
> applications to ensure that their time-sensitive processing receives
> prioritized access to CPU resources. This service enables multimedia
> applications to utilize as much of the CPU as possible without denying
> CPU resources to lower-priority applications

Another option availale to you is to adjust your [thread priorities](https://web.archive.org/web/20100628025406/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958314.aspx) but you need to be very careful not to get to aggressive with this.

Comment: Thats exactly the type of answer I wanted, things that you possibly should be aware of but only few people know. I'll do some reading on MMCSS. Thanks